# Powershell Output - formatting

Tags: powershell

I have the below powershell script and I want the format to show the whole string, as though I was using Format-Table with -Wrap and -Autosize. I've tried using those, but it doesn't show all the needed properties, not sure if I wasn't using it correctly or what was the case.

```
$threshold = 30   #Number of days to look for expiring certificates 

$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)   #Set deadline date 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName  { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | foreach { 
    If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline) { 
        $_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";
        Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} 
    } 
}
```

This is what my output currently looks like:

```
Issuer                                     Subject                                    NotAfter          Expires In (Days)

CN=MASKEDMASKEDMASKED ...   CN=masked.customer.masked.com, OU=...       2/21/2014 5:59:59 PM              -17
CN=MASKEDMASKEDMASKED ...   CN=masked.customer.masked.com, OU=...       2/21/2014 5:59:59 PM              -17
```

Can anyone provide some assistance, please? I basically just need to expand those columns to see all the details.

Comment: @CTravel why would you change `Label="Expires In (Days)"` to `Label="Expires    In (Days)"`? This seems to be inappropriate use of the edit privilege. You're completely changing the functionality of the script

Comment: Im sorry, that was not the plan.. didn't see it change.. it was round the time stackoverflow was going back online.. dont know what went wrong... editing it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan to use the data after these commands, you can pipe them to Format-* as you mentioned.  Select will get you the data, but not the friendly display.  Is there a reason you need it displayed?

Here's a quick example where you get the best of both worlds:

```
#Assign output to a variable
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName  { Dir Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | foreach { 
        If ($_.NotAfter -le $deadline) { $_ | Select Issuer, Subject, NotAfter, @{Label="Expires    In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}} } 
    }

#Write the results to the verbose stream.  Use format table and out-string for appearances
#Change to write-host, debug, error, warning, etc. as needed
    Write-Verbose "Results:`n$($result | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap | Out-String)"

#$result is still a usable object at this point
    $result
```

*edit:  I don't have the reputation to comment on Cole9350's suggestion - don't use ExpandProperty.  That is for expanding a single property...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-ExpandProperty` Parameter of your `Select-Object` cmdlet